# How can I get 1920x1080 video from 1440x1080 Surface?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, xiaomi

I try to create video app with video recording and testing it with Xiaomi Redmi 5 witch has 1440x1080 screen resolution. 
When I try to record video with MediaRecorder I get 1440x1080 video:

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoFileName);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.getWidth(), videoSize.getHeight());
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    //mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(totalRotation);
    mediaRecorder.prepare();
```

When I try to set video size to:

```
videoSize = new Size(1920, 1080);
```

Android Studio made error:

```
Surface with size (w=1920, h=1080) and format 0x22 is not valid, size not in valid set: [1440x1080, 1440x720, 1280x720, 960x720, 960x540, 800x600, 864x480, 800x480, 720x480, 640x480, 640x360, 640x320, 480x368, 480x320, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144]
```

I can record 1920x1080 videos with Xiaomi OS camera, but not with my app.

How can I record better smartphone quality video with Camera2 API?

Here is my Manifest.permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I have only one main activity. So I use

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
setContentView(R.layout.activity); 
}
```

I use this:

```
android { compileSdkVersion 29 buildToolsVersion "29.0.2" defaultConfig { applicationId "com.prod.coverme" minSdkVersion 23 targetSdkVersion 29 versionCode 1 versionName "1.0"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to set manual video size in Android MediaRecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058579/not-able-to-set-manual-video-size-in-android-mediarecorder).

Comment: Not quite. I try to set resolution that bigger than surface.

Comment: change the title. There you wrote 190x1080

Comment: Sorry about that. Changed it.

Comment: add this to your styles.xml <item>"android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

Comment: @forthelulx Could you please provide information on how this effect can allow us to overcome the given error?

Comment: Well, the main idea is getting as much width and height as you can.. so when this flag is enabled for a window, it automatically sets the system UI visibility flags View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE and View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN. maximizing your window

Comment: And to point out, `StreamConfigurationMap` is helpful here. `getOutputSizes()` Method will return an array of the objects prepared for class `SurfaceTexture` which im hoping you are using, since we are dealing with a camera2api. The zeroth element is the resolution you would want — the highest available one. I would check it out before any further investigation.  

Oh and finally, you literally can use something likfe ffmpeg or https://github.com/hoolrory/AndroidVideoSamples

Comment: @forthelulx I use getOutputSizes() and get imageDimension 1440x1080 for max res, because Redmi 5 res is 1440x1080.

Comment: could you post the code where you create and launch the activity? What api number are you using? And post also the manifest file

Comment: I have only one main activity. So I use 
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
}`
I use this:
`android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.prod.coverme"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"`

How can I attach file?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in the Android Studio error message: the resolution you want is not supported because is not in the given set

`[1440x1080, 1440x720, 1280x720, 960x720, 960x540, 800x600, 864x480, 800x480, 720x480, 640x480, 640x360, 640x320, 480x368, 480x320, 352x288, 320x240, 176x144]`.

-Edit

This can mean two things: either the 1980x1020 resolution is not supported by the device, or it is not supported by camera2api. Since you can record 1920x1080 video with the OS camera software, the problem is related to camera2api on redmi 5. Searching on google "redmi 5 and camera2api" I found that camera2api is disabled by default on redmi 5. In order to use apps that use this api (like yours) the user must install a mod from unknown sources in order to enable camera2api. The mod I refer to is from 2018: you can search if the xiaomi has released an equivalent update, so you just have to tell users to update the OS.The only alternative I can suggest at this point is to abandon the use of camera2api, i.e. do not use `SURFACE` as a recording input. Instead of `mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);`

try 
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

Comment: Device camera can record 1920x1080, so I think that it's possible.

Comment: @DenVebber I've been looking a little more into the redmi 5 you're using. I read that you want to use camera2api, that's why you're using Surface instead of Camera as VideoSource. From what I read on google it seems that redmi 5 has camera2api disabled by default, but there are ways to activate it. Since the camera2api is not active, the one you are using does nothing but wrapper for the standard camera api. Perhaps for this reason some resolutions are not available using Surface

Comment: Thanx for it, but how can users will work with it?)

Comment: @DenVebber the user will have to install a mod on his phone to enable camera2api. Searching on google "readmi 5 and api2camera" you will immediately find the file I'm talking about. Feedback says it works but I warn you that not having a readmi5 I don't know if this is true or if it causes problems with other apps.

Comment: I found this, but it's not comfortable for users.

Comment: @DenVebber Of course not, many users will not use the app for this reason. This mod I'm referring to is from 2018: maybe xiaomi released a software update where api2 is enabled to allow users to use these apps without having to download mods from unknown sources. Try searching this way. Unfortunately, I don't have any other knowledge on the subject.

Comment: @DenVebber i edited my answer. Now it includes what I wrote you in the comments and it is a complete (unfortunately not very positive) answer to your question

Comment: when I use MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT Android Studio makes exception:
`29162-29162/com.prod.test E/MediaRecorder: SurfaceMediaSource could not be initialized!
`
For MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA:
`Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.sys.activitylog"...`

Comment: @DenVebber you also have to include Permissions in the Manifest file

Comment: I add this 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: @DenVebber You mean that even with these it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes that's it. I check and get correct permissions.

Comment: mhh, I've never encountered this problem. Maybe it's about how you start the Activity? I don't know how you do it because the code is missing: in general you can't create a new MyActivity. To start a new activity you have to create an Intent and then call the startActivity() method of the Context class.
Also try @forthelulx suggestion